# How do I access an array within an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have a .txt file that has information being split by a comma as such:

```
IN,Indiana,6634007
```

While this is a snippet which accesses that file and splits it:

```
for(int i=0; i < count; i++) {
    line = bufferedReader2.readLine();
    String space[] = line.split(",");
    String abb = space[0];
    String nme = space[1];
    int pop = Integer.parseInt(space[2]);
    states[i] = new State(abb, nme, pop);
    }
```

The purpose of that was so that all the information in the txt file could be accessed, so for example this code would print exactly whats present on the .txt file:

```
System.out.println(states[0]);
```

would print:

```
IN,Indiana,6634007
```

My question is, how would I have it so that I can access the specific part of the array as in how would I print lets say just the name "Indiana" or the population "6634007"?

P.S I'm sorry if the title of my question did not make sense, I did not exactly know how to word it.

Comment: If you have a comma separated file, then you have something close to a CSV file, please check apache commons csv and use it, I believe will help you a lot.

Comment: You can split it again `states[0].split(",")`

Comment: Create a class with fields corresponding to the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere, you have a class called `State`. `states` is an Array of this class. So you can add a getter to `State`:

```
public int getPop() {
    return pop;
}
```

And call it on your Object like this:

```
System.out.println(states[0].getPop());
```

as `states[0]` is simply a `State` object.

Add more getters to access different fields.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what i can realise is, you are using **State** class to store the information. In such case, check the **state** class where the first parameter value is stored. Later to print the corresponding information, access its object variable as SapuSeven mentioned.

For eg.

```
public class State{
     public String a;
     public String b;
     public int c;
     public State(String x, String y, int z){
       a=x;
       b=y;
       c=z;
     } 
 }
```

now u can access like

```
System.out.println(states[0].b);
```

for printing the name of city

**OR**

you can simply print the value using index like this

```
System.out.println(states[0].split(",")[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to print every single line, you can try this like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
    String line = null;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
        list.add(line);

    }

    System.out.println(list.get(0));

    // TODO realease resources
}
```

Comment: No, OP is already able to print whole lines. But he wants to print only the third value (if you split the line at `,`)